# how to remove this type of elements overlap?

Tags: html, css

I have very simple div and anchors which I expect to act as `block` and `inline` element but they have unwanted overlap. I have tried setting `box-sizing:border-box;` and also setting `margin:0` on both elements but no chance.

How should I change the code so all elements stay in their own place?

**Edit:** I am testing the result in Chrome Version 72.0.3626.109 and there is overlap on top of anchor elements and bottom of red div.

[image]

```css
.bar{
 height:20px;
 background:#ff0000;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

.changeTab{
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
  background:#000000;
  color:#ffffff;
  line-height:25px;
  height:25px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"><span></span></div>
<a class="changeTab">Home</a>
<a class="changeTab">About</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `<a>` tag is a `inline` element and it respond differently for `top` and `bottom` `padding` it calculates from the center of the element and `inline` elements doesn't respond to `top` and `bottom` `margin`

http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/

> Inline elements
>
> The W3C’s CSS2 spec defines inline elements as "elements of the source
>   document that do not form new blocks of content; the content is
>   distributed in lines". So, inline content is displayed with no line
>   breaks before or afterwards.

```css
.bar {
  height: 20px;
  background: #ff0000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.changeTab {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  /*line-height: 25px;
  height: 25px;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"><span></span></div>
<a class="changeTab">Home</a>
<a class="changeTab">About</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the display of your 'links' to `inline-block`

```css
.bar{
 height:20px;
 background:#ff0000;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

.changeTab{
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
  background:#000000;
  color:#ffffff;
  height:25px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"><span></span></div>
<a class="changeTab">Home</a>
<a class="changeTab">About</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your links (a) to another display behaviour --> inline-block.
And remove or optimize your heights on the links.

```
.changeTab{
  ....
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vbbrgp)

Answer (score 0):

Add margin-bottom inside the div.
`<div class="bar" style="margin-bottom: 6px;"></div>`